# Proof that $||l||_{1}$ and $||l||_{\infty}$ are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathbf{P}$ The set of polynomials of degree $\leq$ two, with real coefficients in $[0, 1]$, if $l=ax^2+bx+c$ in $\mathbf{P}$, we define the norms $||l||_{1}=|a|+|b|+|c|$ and $||l||_{\infty}=\max_{x\in[0, 1]}{\{|l(x)|\}}$

I want to prove that the rules are equivalent, i.e. that they satisfy for some $k_{1}, k_{2}$

$$k_{1}||l||_{1}\leq||l||_{\infty}\leq k_{2}||l||_{1}$$

Note that, $x, a, b, c\in[0, 1]$ then $0\leq x \leq 1$ so multiplying on the inequality we have that $ax^{2}\leq ax \leq a$, $bx \leq b$ and $c\leq c$ so $ax^{2}+bx+c \leq a+b+c$ and $|ax^{2}+bx+c| \leq |ax^2|+|bx|+|c| \leq |a|+|b|+|c|$, so

$$||l||_{\infty}=\max_{x\in[0, 1]}{\{|ax^2+bx+c|\}} \leq |a|+|b|+|c|=||l||_{1}$$ so for the inequality on the right it is sufficient to take $k_{2}=1$.

Now then, I thought of proposing the following $||l||_{\infty} \geq |c|$, $||l||_{\infty}\geq |a+b+c|$  and $||l||_{\infty} \geq \left|\frac{-b^2}{4a} \right|$ so

$$3\|l\|_{\infty} \geq \max_{x\in[0, 1]}\left\{|c|, |a+b+c|, \left|\frac{-b^2}{4a} \right|\right\} \geq |c| + |a+b+c| + \left|\frac{-b^2}{4a} \right|$$

And it seems that by doing some manipulations you can get the value of the other constant, but I don't see it, any suggestions or changes you can make? I appreciate it!

Comment: All norms are equivalent on finite dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it written out yourself, just use that
$$
||l||_1 = |a| + |b| + |c| \leq \max(|a|,|b|,|c|) + \max(|a|,|b|,|c|) +\max(|a|,|b|,|c|) = 3 ||l||_{\infty}
$$
and divide everything by 3. Then you have the left inequality for $k_1 =\frac{1}{3}$.